# Using DB Browser, how do I Write Changes when running a query?

Tags: sqlite

When using DB Browser, changes are not written to file right away. In order to perform a write, the "Write Changes" button on the GUI needs to be used.

However, I have queries that I want to setup to write to file without me needing to click on this button.

How do I write a query to Write Changes as part of the query?

Comment: The answer to this reads like from a different author, who is not really clear about what the question is asking. Could you [edit] either the quesiton or the answer to avoid that impression and/or make this a more helpful (through being less confusing) pair of Q/A? Alternatively, if you have copied both, the question and the answer from somewhere else, please provide the information of where the original can be found and who the original author is?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a separate "Write Changes" command, but you can run the SQLite specific `vacuum` command to prompt for an immediate write.

This will bring up a write confirmation dialog, which can be accepted by just pressing `Space Bar` to immediately perform the write.

Example:

```
delete from "my_table";
vaccum;
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. I googled for an answer for about 2 hours and then stumbled upon the solution by accident when I combined my delete with a cleanup operation.

Comment: Could you make a [mre] of your answers solution? Ideally based on an [mre] in your question which sets up the need for writing changes.